# TlbImp : error TI0000 : System.ApplicationException - Unable to located specified reference: 'MSDATASRC'

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am moving from windows server 2003 build machine to windows server 2012 and a part of automated build is not working.

This is the command that gives error

```
Z:\>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\bin\TlbImp.exe" /nologo /sysarray /strictref "D:\engtmp\VSFlex8.ocx" /keyfile:"D:\engtmp\MyKey.key" /out:"D:\engtmp\Interop.VSFlex8.dll" /machine:x86
/verbose /reference:MSDATASRC
TlbImp : error TI0000 : System.ApplicationException - Unable to located specified reference: 'MSDATASRC'
```

My windows knowledge is limited, I appreciate any help..

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It is a "file not found" error.  MSDATSRC is mis-spelled.